# I need to create a Java client to interact with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I connect to elasticsearch using Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch has a Java API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

You can use it and do what ever you want.